# Convert PHP seperate page lookup to AJAX lookup

Tags: php, jquery, xml, ajax

I am currently using PHP separate pages to check if a name is valid or not, I would like to convert this to AJAX or JSON so that when you leave the form field it auto checks the name I will be doing this within the jquery code with AJAX i think..

Using separate pages and sending uses back and forth is a lot of hassle just for one form field so I would really like to update.

Here is the current PHP code I am using, all I expect as a response from the server side PHP script is valid yes or not.

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    if (!$name) { $name = $_GET['name']; }
    if (!$name) { echo "Error: Name missing"; }
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("........./checknameavail.php?name=".$name);
    $nameavailable = $xml->available;
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use jQuery ajax functionality? If yes, can you post the code? If no, read its documentation

Comment: There can be no ajax OR json, they are different kinds of things.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using jQuery:

1) create an event handler for [focusout()](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) on your name text field

2) in your event handler, call [jQuery's post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to do an ajax call.

3) in post(), you would send text from your text field to a php script which would check whether the name is valid, and returns a boolean value. And also handle a successful or failed request.

Here's a (shortened) sample from an old project. The user types in a search term, `$.post()` calls a php script which searches for matching recipes, and returns an HTML snippet of any matching recipes. Then that snippet is printed to the div on my my HTML page with id 'results':

```
var searchTerm = $('#txtSearchTerm').val();
  //dumb validation
  if($.trim(searchTerm) != "" ){
    //args: path to script, 
    //[data as a JSON], 
    //[callback function]
    $.post('includes/search.inc.php', 
      {term: searchTerm}, 
      function(data){
        $('#results').html(data);         
       });
  } else { alert('Please enter a search term.')}
```